# Insufficient permissions to create Azure DevOps project while having Owner permission

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

After being invited to a client's Azure account and having "Owner" role + access to "Azure AD user, group, service principal" granted I am able create App Services, import source from Github but when I try to create a DevOps project to start actual work I get an error:

[image]

Following the link towards more details I can see that its about permission issue but if I re-check my permissions:

[image]

It says "Owner" but the scope is: "This resource" - note that these infos are under the single Subscription that my client created, however if I click my name for detailed view on my identity I see "Guest":

[image]

What would be the proper way to grant me global permissions on my clients Azure account?

Thanks!

Comment: probably need more permissions? :)

Comment: I've read the docs and it seem that this is the highest in RBAC (role based access control).

Comment: probably needs more azure ad permissions, try with global admin account. the error clearly suggests that

Comment: Thanks, checking that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a project, it will automatically create an AD App named like `organizationname-projectname-513f22f1-befd-xxxxxxcfe90f1` in the App Registerations in your tenant.

To fix the issue, let the global admin of your tenant to modify the user settings. Navigate to the Azure Active Directory in the portal -> User settings -> set `Users can register applications` to Yes.

[image]

Then in the `Manage external collaboration settings`, set the `Guest users permission are limited`  to No.

[image]

[image]

**Besides**, if you can get an administrator role, no matter the settings are, you can create the app directly.

Comment: Thanks for the nicely elaborated answer, trying it now.

Comment: @EdmondTamas Edited my reply, don't forget to set the `Guest users permission are limited` setting.